# Deserialize from ObjectInputStream to one of the subclasses

Tags: android, serialization, xml-serialization, objectinputstream, simple-framework

I have an abstract class called `Message`:

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public enum MsgType
    {
        TypeA, TypeB
    }

    public String Sender;
    public MsgType Type;
}
```

Which has two subclasses:

```
public class MessageA extends Message
{
    public String A;

    public MessageA()
    {
        Type = MsgType.TypeA;
    }
}

public class MessageB extends Message
{
    public int B;

    public MessageB()
    {
        Type = MsgType.TypeB;
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize objects directly from `ObjectsInputStream` using [*Simple*](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) library by instantiating either `MessageA` or `MessageB` depending on which one is being read from stream.

I've tried doing this:

```
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
Message msg = serializer.read(Message.class, inputStream);
// check whether it's MessageA or MessageB by checking Type
```

But it doesn't work because the compiler can't deserialize `MessageA` or `MessageB` to `Message` class. Also, I'm pretty sure I would lose subclass' fields in the process.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: The link points to a library for doing XML serialization and deserialization, which is written and read using text files. But you are using an ObjectInputStream to read the data, which is useful for reading binary data. Please explain.

Comment: This library has Serializer.validate() methods in various forms. If I understand this correctly, you could use this method to see whether an XML represents MessageA or MessageB. When you know, you can call read with the proper Class parameter.

Comment: I have to deserialize objects in C# too. I don't think it's possible via native Java serialization mechanism.

Comment: Documentation says that `validate()` is used to validate the contents of the XML document against XML schema.

Comment: According to the javadoc, the "schema" is defined by an annotated Java class - not an XML Schema file.

Comment: But Simple is just for Java. It isn't going to help you with C#.

Comment: It doesn't matter. XML format is universal.

Comment: Quite, but then why can't you can use, in Java, what you call a "native" serialization mechanism - the output is XML, and so is the input for deserialization?

Comment: `validate()` seem to return `true` for every possible subclass for some reason. Even in strict mode (whatever that is).

Comment: I lost way too much time on trying to make it work and assumed it's simply incompatible.

Comment: But are you calling it with MessageA.class and then for MessageB.class? They don't have subclasser, or do they?

Comment: No, they don't. I even tried some random stuff like `String.class` and it still passes the validation. I'm pretty sure this function has some other purpose.

Comment: Why don't you use JAXB?

Comment: JAXB doesn't work on Android (I should've mention it).

Comment: Anyway, I've created a demo that shows you can marshal, unmarshal and verify to determine the class that's on an XML file. Works remarkably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        MessageB messageB = new MessageB( "example", 123 );
        File result = new File( "example.xml" );
        serializer.write( messageB, result );
        MessageB msgB = serializer.read( MessageB.class, result );
        System.out.println( msgB );
        try {
            if( serializer.validate( MessageA.class, result ) ){
                System.out.println( "valid for MessageA" );
            }
        } catch( Exception e ){
            System.out.println( "NOT valid for MessageA" );
        }
        try {
            if( serializer.validate( MessageB.class, result ) ){
                System.out.println( "valid for MessageB" );
            }
        } catch( Exception e ){
            System.out.println( "NOT valid for MessageB" );
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Message{
    public enum MsgType {
        TypeA, TypeB
   }
    @Element
    private String sender;
   @Element
    private MsgType type;
    protected Message(){
    }
    protected Message( String s, MsgType t ){
        sender = s;
        type = t;
    }
    public String getSender(){ return sender; }
    public MsgType getType(){ return type; }
    public String toString(){
        return "type=" + type + ", sender=" + sender;
    }
}

@Root
public class MessageA extends Message {
    @Element
    private String a;
    public MessageA(){
    }
    public MessageA( String s, String a ){
        super( s, MsgType.TypeA );
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getA(){ return a; }
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + ", a=" + a;
    }
}
@Root
public class MessageB extends Message {
    @Element
    private int b;
    public MessageB(){
    }
    public MessageB( String s, int b ){
        super( s, MsgType.TypeA );
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int getB(){ return b; }
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + ", b=" + b;
    }
}
```

This works very well.

```
type=TypeA, sender=example, b=123
NOT valid for MessageA
valid for MessageB
```

The XML file is written as:

```
<messageB>
  <sender>example</sender>
  <type>TypeA</type>
  <b>123</b>
</messageB>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I relied solely on `validate()` return value which was supposed to be "true if the document matches the class XML schema" but checking whether an exception is thrown is *actually* working.

Comment: Yeah, this mixture of exception+return value isn't "best practice".

Comment: I thought so too, but since it's not a serious project I'm happy with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add an @Root(name = "...") annotation to each of the subclasses

For example:

```
public interface StringOperation {
    String performOperation(String input);
}

@Root(name = "upperCaseStringOperation")
public class UpperCaseStringOperation implements StringOperation {
    public UpperCaseStringOperation() {
    }

    @Override
    public String performOperation(String input) {
        return (input == null) ? (null) : (input.toUpperCase());
    }
}

@Root(name = "lowerCaseStringOperation")
public class LowerCaseStringOperation implements StringOperation {
    public LowerCaseStringOperation() {
    }

    @Override
    public String performOperation(String input) {
        return (input == null) ? (null) : (input.toLowerCase());
    }
}

@Root(name = "noOpStringOperation")
public class NoOpStringOperation implements StringOperation {
    public NoOpStringOperation() {
    }

    @Override
    public String performOperation(String input) {
        return input;
    }
}

@Root
public class Data {

    @Element
    private String name;

    @Element
    private StringOperation nameOperation;

    @Element
    private String email;

    @Element
    private StringOperation emailOperation;

    public Data() {
        nameOperation = new NoOpStringOperation();
        emailOperation = new NoOpStringOperation();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getProcessedName() {
        return nameOperation.performOperation(getName());
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getProcessedEmail() {
        return emailOperation.performOperation(getEmail());
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setNameOperation(StringOperation operation) {
        this.nameOperation = operation;
    }

    public void setEmailOperation(StringOperation operation) {
        this.emailOperation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Data(name = %s, processedName = %s, email = %s, processedEmail = %s)",
                             getName(),
                             getProcessedName(),
                             getEmail(),
                             getProcessedEmail());
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
        Data before = new Data();
        before.setName("Joseph Wallflower");
        before.setNameOperation(new UpperCaseStringOperation());
        before.setEmail("Joseph.Wallflower@SomeCompany.com");
        before.setEmailOperation(new LowerCaseStringOperation());

        System.out.format("BEFORE: %s%n", before.toString());

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File file = new File(System.getenv("USERPROFILE")+File.separator+"Documents"+File.separator+"simple.xml");
        serializer.write(before, file);
```

Results in:

```
<data>
   <name>Joseph Wallflower</name>
   <nameOperation class="simplexml.UpperCaseStringOperation"/>
   <email>Joseph.Wallflower@SomeCompany.com</email>
   <emailOperation class="simplexml.LowerCaseStringOperation"/>
</data>
```